# Java subString confusion

Tags: java, substring

i was doing a small java code where  data is read through   a file and stored in a `String`
and then using subStrig i  have to  break this string  ,
For  example data is saved like this  `"Hello java $"`  `"Hello word $"` ,  each sentence contains `$` at the end  and i want to break it  on the basis of  `$`

I did try using `indexOf` , `lastindexOf` etc but was not able to do exact logic ,  pleas help me

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\javaprograms\\a.txt));
    while((a=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
       s=s+a;
    // here i have to split  the data that is "Hello java$"  "Hello world$"          

    }
```

Comment: you mention substring in the title yet you have no mention of it in the question itself.  Where is the code you have tried with substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to use a Scanner with custom delimiter?
For example like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("..."));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
sc.useDelimiter("\\$");
while (sc.hasNext())
{
    String text = sc.next();
    System.out.println(text);
    ...
}
```

This code splits your text with "$" as delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
String a = "Hello java $ fff";
System.out.println(a.indexOf("$"));
System.out.println(a.substring(0, a.indexOf("$")));
```

Output:

```
11
Hello java
```

Comment: Yes split method can be used or StringTokenizer can also be useful. But I suspect OP was having some problem with "$" because its special regx character so pointed out that there is not issue using it without escape sequence in these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the split() function in the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, this will allow you to return an array of Strings split around a particular String or regex.

Comment: Apropos nothing in particular, I'm a fan of the Apache Commons Lang library for this - see http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html